# How to drive a 9V common cathode 7 Segment using Arduino and transistors?

Tags: arduino, 7segmentdisplay

I want to make a 4 digit timer with  9V CC 7 segment using arduino.
I tried the circuit below to switch the segments.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOGRA4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The segments turns ON with 0V on pnp and 5V on npn transistor, I assumed 5V on PNP would turn the LED off, but it didn't. Is there any way I can switch the segment LED this way?

Comment: 5V at the PNP's input (R1) still means around 7 V across R1, R3 and R4, that is more than enough to keep the PNP on. You would need around 12 V to turn it off completely.

Comment: @FakeMoustache yeah I tried 12V and it made the pnp off. Now How can I change this circuit to work with 5V?

Comment: Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5V at the PNP's input (R1) still means around 7 V across R1, R3 and R4, that is more than enough to keep the PNP on. You would need around 12 V to turn it off completely. –

You need to shift the level for the PNP, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8miX8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I removed some of the resistors which are not really needed as well.

The base resistors can be a bit higher value as well.

Comment: Use 4.7 k that's a good compromise. 1k is really low, it does not harm anything but the transistors don't need that much base current. 4.7 k with 5 V gives a bit less than 1 mA base current which is more than enough.

Comment: But how is this being extended to drive a four digit 7 segment display? Presumably Q2 will carry the current for all seven segments, in which case 1mA of base current might not be enough for the minimum \$ h_{FE} \$.

Comment: It says 30 mA, so beta can be about 30 and Ib will still be enough. I expect beta to be more than 100 for a 2n2222 btw.

Comment: I read that as 30mA per segment, in which case surely there's up to 210mA through Q2?

Comment: Yes @Finbarr you are right each segment consumes 30mA so the total current for number 0 would be 210 mA on Q2.

Comment: @FakeMoustache - " I expect beta to be more than 100 for a 2n2222 btw." Not in saturation, it won't. And drivers like this must be saturated.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast The beta of 100 I was mentioning is **of course** the beta when **not** in saturation. When in saturation beta drops because one applies more base current than would result from that beta. To be able to know how much base current needs to be applied to drive the transistor into saturation I must first know what the beta is when it is not in saturation. Then apply more Ib, hey presto it's in saturation. Not sure why this always causes confusion even with EEs even more experienced than myself.

Comment: Some EEs say: "when in stauratrion, just use a beta of 10" but when I use a lousy 2n3055 with a non saturated beta of 10 then using Ib = 1C/10 will not put it in saturation now will it.

Comment: @FakeMoustache So do you think 4.7K would be ok? even for 210 mA Ic current?

Comment: That would be on the edge I guess, I would just try it, see how much Vce develops across the transistors. If it is more than 0.3 - 0.5 V you could try a lower base resistor value like 2.2 k ohm or even the 1 k ohm as in your initial circuit.

Comment: @FakeMoustache - I quite agree with most of what you say. But your circuit uses 4.7k/5V on the LED NPN , which will require a beta of 30 or so to saturate at the indicated 30 mA. Of course, 30 mA is incompatible with the 10 mA or so which the 100 ohm R8 will produce. So 4.7k is fine for your circuit as presented, but this does not seem to be what the OP wanted.  The level shifter is fine.